# OuterRef not allowed in an annotation?

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango, django-postgresql

I'm trying to annotate a queryset of `Entity` objects with the distance between two related [polygons](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#polygon); each entity has its own set of related polygons, stored in the `shape` attribute of foreign-key-related `EntityFeature` objects. EntityFeatures are named, and I need to find the distance between two named features for each entity:

```
Entity.objects.all().annotate(
    distance = ExpressionWrapper(
        Subquery(
            EntityFeature.objects.get(
                entity__id = OuterRef('id'),
                name = 'feature_a'
            ).shape.centroid.distance(
                Subquery(
                    EntityFeature.objects.get(
                        entity__id = OuterRef(OuterRef('id')),
                        name = 'feature_b'
                    ).shape.centroid
                )
            )
        ), output_field = DecimalField()
    )
)
```

As soon as it reaches the first OuterRef, I get `ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.` I've tried removing the first subquery and using `F('id')`, but then I think `id` refers to the EntityFeature's id instead and it throws `DoesNotExist: EntityFeature matching query does not exist.`

Am I going about this the wrong way? What's the best method to find the distance between two related objects for each thing in a queryset?

[python 2.7.15 / django 1.11]